# Cross-browser, javascript getAttribute() method?

Tags: javascript

trying to determine a decent, cross browser method for obtaining attributes with javascript? assume javascript library use (jQuery/Mootools/etc.) is not an option.

I've tried the following, but I frequently get "attributes" is null or not an object error when IE tries to use the "else" method. Can anyone assist?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//...
    getAttr: function(ele, attr) {
      if (typeof ele.attributes[attr] == 'undefined'){
        return ele.getAttribute(attr);
      } else {
        return ele.attributes[attr].nodeValue;
      }
    },
//...
</script>


<div>
 <a href="http://www.yo.com#foo">Link</a>
</div>
```

using the above html, in each browser, how do I getAttr(ele, **'href'**)? (assume selecting the ele node isn't an issue)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With regard to your question's update, you could try this.

It may be overkill, but if `getAttribute()` and the dot notation don't return a result, it iterates through the `attributes` object to try to find a match.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/4ZwNs/

```
var funcs = {
    getAttr: function(ele, attr) {
        var result = (ele.getAttribute && ele.getAttribute(attr)) || null;
        if( !result ) {
            var attrs = ele.attributes;
            var length = attrs.length;
            for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
                if(attrs[i].nodeName === attr)
                    result = attrs[i].nodeValue;
        }
        return result;
    }
};

var result = funcs.getAttr(el, 'hash');
```

It's up to you to do some cross-browser testing, though. :o)

---

Using `ele.attributes`, you need to access them by index, as in:

```
ele.attributes[0].nodeName;   // "id" (for example)
ele.attributes[0].nodeValue;  // "my_id" (for example)
```

Trying to pass `attributes` an attribute name appears to return a value whose `typeof` is `object`, so your `else` code is running even though `ele.attributes[attr]` doesn't give you the value you want.

Comment: I updated the question to be a little more specific. How would I specify that I want the attr "href" or "hash" using your method?

Comment: works great in Chrome/FF, testing in IE8, I get:
Object doesn't support this property or method on this line:
var result = ele.getAttribute(attr) || ele[attr] || null;

Comment: eh starting to think it's the selector I'm passing to it causing the issue

Comment: @tester - Works for me in IE7 and IE8. Maybe try replacing `ele.getAttribute(attr)` with `(ele.getAttribute && ele.getAttribute(attr))`. EDIT: Let me know if it was the selector.

Comment: @patrick dw, so it appears it's how I'm going about using this. What you've done works perfectly.. Having some trouble debugging ie's issue with how I'm doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/N8CxL/

would appreciate any assistance you can further provide.

Comment: @tester - Not sure. At first it was showing that `obj` in `bind` method was null, then it stopped. Maybe there's an issue with your DOMReady?

Comment: it's something up with my bind method.. something about how 'this' doesn't properly represent the current object, so I can't use your getAttr method properly..

Comment: ah I figured it out.. it was the bind method.. I was going if (obj[i].addEventListener) {... instead of if (obj.addEventListener) {...

Comment: @tester - Glad you got it figured out. :o)

Comment: Attributes are not the same as properties. Please do not mix them up and treat them as being equivalent.

Comment: @tester - Updated the answer. See comment above from @Tim Down.

Comment: Patrick: my comment was a bit aggressive. Sorry. The general confusion among developers over properties and attributes (largely the fault of jQuery and its confusing `attr()` method) is something of bugbear for me.

Comment: Perhaps I'm a little late to chime in here, but I think there is a typo.  I think you mean to use `attrs[i].nodeName` and `attrs[i].nodeValue` in the loop.

Comment: Doesn't testing if( !result ) mean that a false-y result, like empty string, will cause the loop to run? Suggest using if (result !== null) instead.

Comment: @enigment you're right and also, there's no need to loop if the getAttribute method is present, but the attribute is not set.
So I'd change the if condition to be (result !== null && !ele.getAttribute)

Answer (score 16):

For the vast majority of cases you can simply use the built in `getAttribute` function.

e.g.

```
ele.getAttribute(attr)
```

According to [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html) this should work on all major browsers (IE >= 6 included), with a minor exception:

In IE5-7, accessing the `style` attribute gives an object, and accessing the `onclick` attribute gives an anonymous function wrapped around the actual content.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to access properties of ele before you've established if those properties exist. Try this kind of evidence chain:

```
if (ele.attributes && ele.attributes[attr] && typeof ele.attributes[attr] == 'undefined')
```

etc.

Comment: i suppose that will get rid of my error (and thanks), but how say I used my method $.getAttr($anchor, 'href');

how do I get the href from a <a href="#"> in IE6-8?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I updated the bottom of the question to specify what I'm trying to get at (the href of a selected link)