# how to highlight gridview cell on the mouse click in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript

```
$('#<%= gr.ClientID%>tr').click(function () {
            $(this).addClass('highlightCell');
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('highlightCell');
        });
    });
<asp:GridView ID="gr" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Name" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
```

this code work for mouseover but not for mouse click.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: code seems like you change table row color on click. it not working? Possibly you need `$('#<%= gr.ClientID%> td')` instead

Comment: that's a wrong syntax for jQuery `.click` event. you can have just one handler inside the click

Comment: Use This Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543683/vb-net-mouse-click-single-cell-of-gridview-change-backcolor-and-output-cell-pos

Comment: possibly you try attach event to rows before render, try move script after grid declaration

Answer (score 0):

so basically, what you need is to do something(highlighting the row) when mouse is pressed over a given cell, and remove the highlighting when mouse is released. jQuery `.click` is not what you should be using. You should be looking at jQuery's `.mouseup` and `.mousedown` events.

try this:

```
$('td', '#<%= gr.ClientID%>')
  .mouseup(function() {
       $(this).removeClass('highlightCell');
  })
  .mousedown(function() {
    $(this).addClass('highlightCell');
  });
```

also, you need to bind the events to the `TDs` of your gridView, so you need to look for tds only inside your gridView, learn how to scope the dom traversal of the jquery. you should scope restrict your selector like this :

```
$('selector', 'scope')
```