# How to access attribute values on a JavaScript DOM Node Element?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn how to use native JavaScript without relying on jQuery. I would like to get the value of a specific attribute on an element. How can I do this without using jQuery? If there are inconsistencies between browsers, please mention them.

```js
myImage = document.getElementById("logo");
console.log('myImage src attribute value');
console.log('myImage data-foo attribute value');
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="logo.png" data-foo="bar">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-browser, javascript getAttribute() method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755227/cross-browser-javascript-getattribute-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) to assess the value.

```js
myImage = document.getElementById("logo");
console.log(myImage.getAttribute('src'));
console.log(myImage.getAttribute('data-foo'));
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="http://placehold.it/500x500" data-foo="bar">
```

---

For the HTML5 `data-` attributes, you can still access with the conventional method, or even use [`.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) (but only with [HTML5-compliant browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset)), i.e: `.dataset.foo`:

```js
myImage = document.getElementById("logo");
console.log(myImage.getAttribute('src'));
console.log(myImage.dataset.foo);
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="http://placehold.it/500x500" data-foo="bar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check W3C DOM specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/idl-definitions.html, in particular [Element.getAttribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-666EE0F9)().